# How can I clear the cache on a cake.php site

Tags: php, cakephp

I have inherited an older website that is pretty basic, just a landing page to display a team and individual pages for these members.

I've been working on updating the site with the new team members but the updates are taking ages to go through.

Is there a way to clear the sites app/tmp/cache/models folder? I'm not the most familiar with more barebones cake.php sites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you can just Delete the file that's in the folder and it will come back with a refreshed version. :)